# One signal integration with react native

Tags: react-native-ios, onesignal

I'm working on integrating One-Signal with react native, 
I followed One-Signal Docs.
now when I try to build on my iOS simulator I recieve this error:

```
OneSignal-inAppMessageClicked is not a supported event type for 
RCTOneSignalEventEmitter. Supported events are: OneSignal- 
remoteNotificationReceived, OneSignal-remoteNotificationOpened, 
OneSignal-idsAvailable, OneSignal-emailSubscription
```

On the actual device everything seems to work.

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "^0.59.9",
"react-native-onesignal": "^3.3.0",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the SDK that has since been fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I'm getting these errors even with new versions of SDK:

> 2022-03-03 08:48:11.130
> [error][tid:com.facebook.react.OneSignalQueue][RCTEventEmitter.m:78]
> `OneSignal-inAppMessageWillDisplay` is not a supported event type for
> RCTOneSignalEventEmitter. Supported events are:
> ...
> [error][tid:com.facebook.react.OneSignalQueue][RCTEventEmitter.m:78]
> `OneSignal-inAppMessageWillDismiss` is not a supported event type for
> ...
> [error][tid:com.facebook.react.OneSignalQueue][RCTEventEmitter.m:78]
> `OneSignal-inAppMessageDidDismiss` is not a supported event type for
> RCTOneSignalEventEmitter. Supported events are:
> ...
> [error][tid:com.facebook.react.OneSignalQueue][RCTEventEmitter.m:78]
> `OneSignal-inAppMessageDidDisplay` is not a supported event type for
> RCTOneSignalEventEmitter. Supported events are:
> `OneSignal-permissionChanged`, `OneSignal-subscriptionChanged`,
> `OneSignal-notificationWillShowInForeground`,
> `OneSignal-remoteNotificationOpened`, `OneSignal-inAppMessageClicked`,
> `OneSignal-emailSubscriptionChanged`,
> `OneSignal-smsSubscriptionChanged`

I have the current version installed:

> ```
> "react": "17.0.2",
> "react-native": "0.62.2",
> "react-native-onesignal": "^4.3.7",
> ```

Is there any way to workarround these errors?